# MSDN Intro: Undefined Reference to WinMain@16

Tags: c++, msdn

I am following the MSDN tutorial for setting up a basic Windows application with C++, and it is not compiling properly in Code::Blocks.  Similar questions have been asked here before, but I was unable to find any with a solution and I am able to provide a detail that I did not see any others providing.

For now I was able to get it working by converting their wWinMain function to WinMain, but I would like to know what is going on since my understanding is that WinMain is intended for 16-bit operating systems.

**Their Code:**

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

**Working Code:**

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

**And The Full Sample Code:**

```
ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
        );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

**Tutorial URL:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381409(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer!

Comment: You can get the information contained in the parameters through functions anyway (e.g., `GetCommandLineW`), which allows you to just use the standard C++ `int main()`.

Comment: Will the compiler know which version of WinMain to reference?  The MSDN tutorial alluded to this but also insinuated that it was less efficient and that there could be other problems inherent in the approach.

Comment: I'm guessing MSVC has support for both non-standard main functions, but that your CodeBlocks setup (likely GCC+MinGW) only has support for `WinMain`. Windows programs are most commonly written in Visual Studio and compiled right there with MSVC. I know things like MinGW attempt to keep up and support Windows programming, but not everything is the same. For example, last I checked, a lot of the new winapi functions were not in the headers that came with MinGW.

Comment: Great to know!  I wanted to stick with Code::Blocks for a generic implementation that I would be used to when I began cross-OS application development, but perhaps I'll look into using Visual instead.